# Custom Postype specific changes in admin panel

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, title

I have this small bit of code which does exactly what I need. But I want to limit its use to one Custom Post Type (CPT) only.

```
add_filter('sanitize_title', 'my_custome_slug');
function my_custome_slug($title) {
    return str_replace('-', '', $title);
}
```

I've tried the following code with no luck:

```
function my_custome_slug($title){ 
global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type == 'customposttype') {
         return str_replace('*', '-', $title);
         }
    } 
add_filter('sanitize_title', 'my_custome_slug');
```

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Sorry i was not clear in my post.

Wordpress is taking "Post Titles" and change them to "post-titles" in urls when we first enter the title in any new posts. My original question was , for a specific custom post type, i need to remove "-" in urls of the posts. So they will be "posttitles"

[image]

I thought the problem was using "sanitize_title" because every other example i found for custom post specific content loading in Admin panel works. But once i use sanitize_title in those examples, the result would simply make a blank url under the title field.

The first code i've shared is doing this already. I've tried to limit it's function to a specific custom posttype but it simply didnt work.

I need this feature and i saw its already possible. I just need to limit it to a specific custom post type.  This is rather a backend problem (due to some internal structre) and not a frontend problem. Otherwise i would have tried it with htacess. So our main target is wordpress publish page on admin panel.

Comment: `sanitize_title` is used a lot. This could be tricky, where do you want this applied? In what context? Save? Display? What?

Comment: I want to use it on newposts of a particular custompost type at admin panel.

The first code changes "Post*Title" to "post-title"  OR "Post Title" to "posttitle" (however you adjust)
when its first written on the title field.

I want to only apply this effect to one custompost type. I want rest of the blog to function normally like "Post title" to "post-title".

The first code works but the second one breaks and doesnt load anything on the title field.

Answer (score 0):

A filter *always* needs to return something. So in the second example you should try `return $title;` after the `if` statement so it doesn't break other posts.

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'my_custome_slug' );
function my_custome_slug( $title )
{ 
    return ( 'customposttype' === $GLOBALS['post']->post_type )
        ? str_replace( '*', '-', $title )
        : $title;
}
```

I'm not completely sure why you're hooking that callback to `sanitize_title`. Imo it would be easier to just save the post different and [using the `save_post` hook to alter the title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73529/385).

#### Edit

As previously guessed and as the OP stated in the comments (that above was just a *random* snippet found on the internet), here's an update how to actually alter a posts title.

The function [`get_the_title()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_title/) gets called by the function `the_title()` and either one or the other should be used to output the title for posts, pages and custom post types. `get_the_title()` returns the title inside a filter:

```
return apply_filters( 'the_title', $title, $id );
```

So the easiest way is to add a callback on exactly that and alter the output there:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse136615_title_str_replace', 10, 2 );
function wpse136615_title_str_replace( $title, $id )
{
    $post = get_post( $id );
    return ( 'your_custom_post_type_name' === $post->post_type )
        ? str_replace( '*', '-', $title )
        : $title;
}
```

Simply replace `your_custom_post_type_name` with your real custom post types name (see the arguments used in `register_post_type()` if you're unsure about the name).

Comment: Hey Kaiser

I've tried your code (pasted in to my function.php file) but it doesnt effect neither the custom post or any other post.

I've changed 'customposttype' with my customposttype slug. Perhaps i did it wrong?

Also i didnt write this code but found it on the internet.  It does what i want globally but i cannot narrow its response to particullar customposts.

Comment: Well, I thought you didn't just post a random snippet, but actually used `sanitize_title()` on your title somewhere. I'll file an edit, but so far it's mostly guessing and not really giving an answer to a real question. :/

Comment: Hey Kaiser. Thanks alot for taking time to look in to this problem. As for the code;

Oh, the original question was in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135514/change-wordpress-post-urls-in-publish-page-with-ajax Where i thought it was about Ajax.

As ive mentioned before, it does what i want but it does it to all post types. 

Ive tried your code new code but it didnt do a thing again.  Hope with me sharing the original question, it would make it a bit clearer. Can you may be check the original question and see if it makes sense? Thanks alot again

Comment: @user3067368 No, I'm not going to check that question. It would be much better if you edit your question and show us what the part of your template that calls the title looks like.

Comment: Hey Kaiser, i've included further details in my original post. Hope this would show my intention a bit better.

Comment: @user3067368 Yes, this is a completely different topic. You're talking about slugs, permalinks and rewrite stuff, not about titles. My answer is worthless in that case.